# I installed ICQ on Ubuntu, but I cannot uninstall it?

Tags: 16.04, uninstall

Recently, I got nostalgic and installed ICQ on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
The installation was succesful, but I later found out that ICQ has multiple issues and doesn't work the way it used to. 
So, I decided to uninstall the program.
Online I found 2 ways to do this, but the icon is still visible on my ribbon and the program still works.
Here are the ways that I used to uninstall the program: 
https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/licq-plugin-icq?action=remove
http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/a/account-plugin-icq/uninstall/index.html
I opened a terminal and tried both solutions, but neither worked.
Does anyone know how to get rid of ICQ since it has become useless, since it asked my to fill in a password before I even was able to set one!

Comment: Which way you used to install it?

Comment: When installed, was `licq-plugin-icq` the only package installed? and was it installed via aptitude (`apt` or `apt-get` etc)?   If you installed say a tarball, those commands won't help you.

Comment: I installed the 32 bits package that you can find on this page:
https://icq.com/linux/en
As far as I remember, I did not use any sudo apt get commands.

Comment: It was a tarball. What should I do to uninstall this program?

Comment: @SebastianStark I installed it as a tar ball

Comment: Since I haven't found an answer to my question, I am now further investigating the matter. I have found a number of interesting links which I will share when my answer is comple. Bare with me for the time being!